# How to make background view transparent but image without transparency in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I want to show an image on whole screen and background should be transparent but image should not be transparent. Please help me with this.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have made research but i am not getting the result i wanted. I am setting image view's background color black and setting it alpha to low value but the image is also getting transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please select background color black and Opacity 50%

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i do so my image also getting transparent. But i want the background to be transparent not the image. Please help me with this.

Comment: @VaishaliHunagund this is view background color apply not image

Comment: i tried with that also but my image is also getting transparent.

Comment: @VaishaliHunagund same like your screenshot

Comment: @VaishaliHunagund your code not working because alph is whole UIImageview on apply. my suggestion also working storyboard

Comment: Thank you so much... It is working!.. Actually i had set background color for view and set alpha to lower value but it wasn't working. Now i set the opacity as you said it is working fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @VaishaliHunagund wlc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I guess you just have to set the `UIImageView`s `backgroundColor` to `.clear` and define the color of your `UIViewController`s view holding the `UIImageView` to whichever color you want / think fits.